# encodeURI space as % instead of %20

Tags: typescript

I want to hit an API by navigating to path as
 this.router.navigate(["salesfunnel",5,userId,this.startDate,status,this.endDate, isSource]);

At that point my userId is "Digital Market". There is a space in between.

but to correctly navigate to the required path i want to encode it like
"Digital%Market".

As of now , URI is : http://103.21.187.5:8090/tripleplay/lead/filter?type=Digital Market&status=PAYMENT_PENDING_EKYC_LEAD ,

there is space between Digital and Market

but the required URI is : http://103.21.187.5:8090/tripleplay/lead/filter?type=Digital%Market&status=PAYMENT_PENDING_EKYC_LEAD.

I tried it doing like encodeURI(userId) and then passing it as parameter to router.navigate() method , buy its showing URI as:

http://103.21.187.5:8090/tripleplay/lead/filtertype=Digital%20Market&status=PAYMENT_PENDING_EKYC_LEAD

```
Present URI:

URI is : http://103.21.187.5:8090/tripleplay/lead/filter? 
type=Digital Market&status=PAYMENT_PENDING_EKYC_LEAD

Required URI:

URI is : http://103.21.187.5:8090/tripleplay/lead/filter? 
type=Digital%Market&status=PAYMENT_PENDING_EKYC_LEAD
```

Finally , i want Digital Market to be Digital%Market but not Digital%20Market

Comment: but %20 equal ascii character 32 (or space), if you don't want that, then just send it as Digital+Market from your end?

Comment: How do you generate the url?

Comment: @Icepickle `%` must be percent-encoded in the URI

Comment: @zerkms true, I am just wondering what the usecase is he is trying to cover

Comment: I am trying to give route by passing four parameters and all other parameters are going fine,but  in userId, if there is space , then it passes like Digital Market , but it should be like Digital%Market , to correctly hit the Api and to correctly navigate to the required path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found the answer , i have just used replace method of typescript like

userId.replace(" ","%").

It will replace spaces by % sign.

Thats it!

Comment: That really doesn't help `encodeUri`, or even making your code to be conform with webstandards, and as zerkms has explained above, % will also be encoded. So I believe you are looking for a wrong solution because you are making bad assumptions

Comment: So, is there any other standard way to resolve that issue, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, use `encodeUriComponent` which will pass it like `Digital%20Market`, which should be the correct way to send a space to a backend in a querystring. The backend will see it like `Digital Market` and you don't have to do anything about it